# Ошибка с методом users.get (API Вконтакте)

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте! Выполняю запрос к API Вконтакте, а именно, метод users.get.

```
    let obj = [];

    sendRequest('users.get', {user_ids:users}, function(data) {
            obj = data.response;
            console.log(obj);

    });
```

Где users - это массив из айдишников профилей вк.
Проблема в том, что:

- если этот массив состоит из менее, чем около 150 айдишников, то
  массив объектов с конкретной информацией выводится
- при большем же количестве (до 1000) выводит ошибку

> GET
>   https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids%5B%5D=974848&user_ids%5B%5D=15…256fd25&callback=jQuery321042992530702542253_1495187347158&_=1495187347160
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Скорее всего, я нарушаю какие-то ограничения. Буду рад помощи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте документацию, в запросе можно указывать до 1000 номеров.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так я и даю запрос с количеством до 1000 номеров)
Проблема в том, что, например, запрос на 850 номеров выдаёт ошибку,

Comment: @НиколайЖуренко возможно js библиотека шлет параметры GET запросом, которые не укладываются в лимит, посмотрите через отладчик код статуса. Если 414 - то точно.

Comment: Точно. Вот, нашёл подробности: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string
Спасибо за ответ! Буду думать над разбивкой запроса на части или другими способами решения этой проблемы)

Comment: @НиколайЖуренко в API можно делать POST запрос.

Comment: Спасибо большое!